# Simplification of Three Integrals Partial Differential Equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am using Kirchoff's formula to solve wave equation in three dimensions, and I have the following three integrals:

$\int_{\partial B(x_0,t)}t*|y-x_0|^2dS(y)$

$\int_{\partial B(x_0,t)}|y-x_0|^6dS(y)$

$\int_{\partial B(x_0,t)}\nabla|y-x_0|^6\cdot (y-x_0)dS(y)$

How can I get rid of the integrals? What formulas/theorems can I use to get out of them?

Comment: $dS(y) = t^2 \:d\Omega$, where $d\Omega$ is the angular measure of spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First translate all of the integrals to get

$$I_1 = \int_{\partial B(0,t)}t|y|^2\:dS(y)$$

$$I_2 = \int_{\partial B(0,t)}|y|^6\:dS(y)$$

$$I_3 = \int_{\partial B(0,t)}\nabla|y|\cdot y\:dS(y)$$

For the first two integrals, note that

$$I(n) = \int_{\partial B(0,t)} |y|^n \:dS(y) = \int_{S^2} t^{n+2} d\Omega = 4\pi t^{n+2}$$

meaning

$$I_1 = t\cdot I(2) = 4\pi t^5$$

$$I_2 = I(6) = 4\pi t^8$$

Lastly using that

$$\nabla |y| = \frac{y}{|y|}$$

we get that

$$I_3 = \int_{\partial B(0,t)} |y| \:dS(y) = I(1) = 4\pi t^3$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. I did not realize that we could translate all of the integrals by $x_0$. Thank you very much!